# How to understand without clause?

Tags: grammar, clauses

I am reading this [tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/the-basics), and run into the following statement:

> This is an SHA-1 checksum of the commit’s contents, which ensures that the commit will never be corrupted without Git knowing about it.

I don't know undetstand this sentence clearly, especially "`... without Git knowing about it`". Could anyone help to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way "without" is normally used in such constructions, you can "invert" the sentence to understand the meaning better. "No *a* without *b*" is often equivalent to "if *a*, then *b*." So your example becomes:

> This is an SHA-1 checksum of the commit’s contents, which ensures that if a commit is ever corrupted, Git will know about it.